# How to make a turtle draw above another one?

Tags: python, drawing, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm making a project where I have a turtle drawing a black line, but following it is another turtle drawing a white line. I want this white line to draw over the black line to "erase" the black line, but the black line remains above the white line.

I am programming this on trinket.io

Here's my code:

```
import turtle 

#create elements
pen = turtle.Turtle()
follow = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()


#create variables
positions = [0,-180,0,-180,0,-180,0,-180,0,-180,0,-180,0,-180,0,-180,0,-180,0,-180]


#moving functions
def move_left():
  if pen.xcor() > -180:
    pen.goto(pen.xcor()-10,pen.ycor())
def move_right():
  if pen.xcor() < 180:
    pen.goto(pen.xcor()+10,pen.ycor())
def move_up():
  if pen.ycor() < 180:
    pen.goto(pen.xcor(),pen.ycor()+10)
def move_down():
  if pen.ycor() > -180:
    pen.goto(pen.xcor(),pen.ycor()-10)


#pen setup
pen.speed(1000)
pen.penup()
pen.goto(0,-180)
pen.left(90)
pen.pendown()

follow.left(90)
follow.color("#FFFFF1")
follow.width(50)


#adjust frame refresh settings
pen.tracer(0,0)
rate = 0
refresh = 0


#game functionality
def game():
  screen.onkey(move_left, 'left')
  screen.onkey(move_right, 'right')
  screen.onkey(move_up, 'up')
  screen.onkey(move_down, 'down')
  follow.goto(positions[0],positions[1])
  positions.append(pen.xcor())
  positions.append(pen.ycor())
  positions.pop(0)
  positions.pop(0)


#wait for keys
screen.listen()


#loop
while True:
  game()
  if refresh < rate:
    refresh = refresh + 1
  else:
    pen.update()
    #print(positions)
    refresh = 0
```

How can I fix my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to invoke each `screen.onkey()` instance once, they gain nothing by being called (indirectly) in a loop.  Also, it's not clear why `positions` is preinitialized with ten positions.

I'm going to guess that you want a turtle that leaves a trail but that trail has a limited length and the end of it disappears as new trail is laid down.  And from your description, you want this to work in **trinket.io** turtle which means we can't use features like `stamps` to make this cleaner.

Below is my rework of your code, that I've tested on **trinket.io**, which leaves behind it 20 line segments. The oldest line segment disappears as a new one is laid down:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

NUMBER_SEGMENTS = 20

# moving functions
def truncate():
    if len(positions) >= NUMBER_SEGMENTS:
        follower.setposition(positions.pop(0))

    screen.update()

def move_left():
    pen.setheading(180)

    if pen.xcor() > -180:
        pen.forward(10)
        positions.append(pen.position())

    truncate()

def move_right():
    pen.setheading(0)

    if pen.xcor() < 180:
        pen.forward(10)
        positions.append(pen.position())

    truncate()

def move_up():
    pen.setheading(90)

    if pen.ycor() < 180:
        pen.forward(10)
        positions.append(pen.position())

    truncate()

def move_down():
    pen.setheading(270)

    if pen.ycor() > -180:
        pen.forward(10)
        positions.append(pen.position())

    truncate()

# create elements
screen = Screen()

# adjust frame refresh settings
screen.tracer(0)

refresh = 0

# pen setup
pen = Turtle()
pen.speed('fastest')
pen.penup()
pen.sety(-180)
pen.setheading(90)
pen.pendown()

follower = pen.clone()
follower.hideturtle()
follower.width(3)
follower.color('#F9F9F9')

# create variables
positions = []

# wait for keys
screen.onkey(move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(move_right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(move_up, 'Up')
screen.onkey(move_down, 'Down')
screen.listen()
screen.update()
screen.mainloop()
```

Not perfect, but **trinket.io** ties our claws a bit.  Is this roughly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, thank you this is very helpful! I was getting kind of frustrated but this solution works very well, thanks so much!